# ExpressJS: How to know when a request has finished?

Tags: javascript, node.js, setinterval, express

In an ExpressJS set up on top of NodeJS, I have a bit of code like this:

```
app.get('/keys/readresults/:keyname', basic_auth, function(req,res){
    res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/json'});
    setInterval(
        go_to_database_and_get('stuff', function (database_replies) {
        res.write(database_replies)
        })
    ,5000);
});
```

The code is wrote like that for simplicity (if anyone wants the real code I'm happy to post it in some pastebin).

What happens when I `curl -u username:password http://localhost:4000/keys/readresults/key` is exactly what I wanted to happen: I get a 200 status header, it checks the database for any results I want and writes the response back to me, then waits 5 seconds and searches for new results in the database and writes the response again, and so on every interval of 5 seconds.

The problem is that when I exit curl, the loop keeps on going forever. **How do I tell express or nodejs that it's supposed to end that loop** (with clearInterval I guess) **as soon as the request has ended ?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`req.on("close")`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.10/api/http.html#event_close_)

So simply

```
app.get('/keys/readresults/:keyname', basic_auth, function(req,res){
    res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/json'});
    var no = setInterval(
        go_to_database_and_get('stuff', function (database_replies) {
        res.write(database_replies)
    });
    ,5000);
    req.on("close", function() {
        clearInterval(no);
    });
});
```

Comment: @JoaoPintoJeronimo you will find that the express `req` and `res` objects extend the native `HTTPRequest` and `HTTPResponse` objects in node.js core. So fall back on those methods

Comment: No longer works in Express 4, see my post. In a nutshell, use `on-finished` middleware.

Answer (score 12):

`req.on('close', ...)` no longer works in Express 4. Use the [`on-finished`](https://github.com/jshttp/on-finished) middleware.

Comment: This is no longer true, or at least `req.on('close', ...)` is still indirectly referenced on the Express 4.x documentation. ["The req object is an enhanced version of Node’s own request object and supports all built-in fields and methods."](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req)

Answer (score 1):

With express 4.X it is `req.on("end", () => {})`, it is better to add this as a express middleware.

Yeah but `on-finished` npm package works too.